# Acumatica - Generic Inquiry via REST

Tags: rest, acumatica

I have used this [blog post](https://www.acumatica.com/blog/contract-based-apis-in-generic-inquiries/) to attempt to setup an endpoint to retrieve generic inquiry data but I appear to be missing something. Our default endpoint is on Contract 1 so I did not extend that endpoint, is that necessary to get this to work? We have another custom endpoint and I setup the generic inquiry as laid out in the blog post but when I make the PUT request via postman with the "$expand=Result" parameter I receive a 500 and exception error "The given key was not present in the dictionary".

I am not super familiar with Acumatica or generic inquiries but from that blog post and other resources my understanding is that in order to retrieve the results of a generic inquiry it cannot be setup as a top-level resource or else you will only receive 1 record. I am trying to retrieve the entire list of records.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Here is a screenshot of the setup:
[image: Screenshot of Endpoint Setup]

Comment: The 500 error seems to suggest that the entity you're trying to retrieve doesn't exist.  If you don't have the GI set up as a top-level entity, what IS the top-level entity?  Have you tried using the GI object as the top-level entity?

Comment: I guess I did not phrase that correctly. I do have the GI as the top-level entity but no fields for it. Below that I have a Detail object that contains the 3 fields from the GI that I want to return and they are mapped to Result.

Comment: I don't know that I can help much in that case, except to wonder if there is a reason you must use a GI?  You can select multiple records based upon a condition and even specify what fields to return without using a GI.  More info here: https://help-2020r2.acumatica.com/?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=775ca16b-cba6-4c1d-89d5-c1df7833bfea

Comment: I don't know that I have to use GI but I tried to use an entity as available in the system by adding it to my custom endpoint but I receive a response of null. I would copy the Default endpoint but in our system it is on Contract 1. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you copy the default endpoint and just confirm you did the custom one correctly?

Comment: Yea that won't work because when I extend it, it remains on Contact 1 which does not consume REST calls. Any other ideas?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your custom endpoint entity?

Comment: Thanks! I have added a screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

The error message you describe usually indicates something missing with respect to the endpoint.  Per the blog post - did you define the endpoint like this (which is the correct structure)?:
[image: Example Endpoint for GI]

If you are not sure, please post a picture of what you created in your custom endpoint, and I will see if I can assist from there.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have added the screenshot. I am not using all of the fields from the inquiry. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Thank you for posting the picture.  You do not need to use all of the fields from the GI.    I believe I see the issue --- please note the difference in your endpoint vs the one in the blog post.  You need to have the "Result" on the right hand side of the colon.   The name "Result" is how you reference what you want to get back from the GI.    You need to re-generate your detail level and switch up the naming to be set up as    BillingRulesInq : Result

Comment: Thank you for hanging with me. When I go to setup the entity ("Create Entity") I set "Result" to be the field name as per the blog post and then selected a name for the Object Name. Whenever I do that it generates with the Result on the left and the Object Name on the right. Is this an issue with the Generic Inquiry itself?

Comment: No it's not - it may be that the blog post had it backward.  Can you do it the other way?

Answer (score 0):

I've actually been working on the same thing, referencing the same article.

I am able to get it to work as described.  One question, are you specifying the $filter parameter?  I only get this error when I try to use a filter.  I am able to call the new endpoint and get back full results.

I found your post searching for a way to use a filter or I trying to find out if there is anyway to pass parameters to the GI from the rest call.